# Fedora 9 (64bit) won't recognize 8G of RAM

Tags: linux, 64-bit, memory, fedora

This is really a question about whether or not it is absolutely necessary for me to upgrade my Fedora.

I just upgraded my computer with a couple more sticks of RAM and have it up to 8G now.  I duel boot so I know that Vista (64bit) recognizes my 8G, and Memtest86+ recognizes my 8G, but for some reason Fedora 9 (64bit) says it has 3.1 G RAM.  Is this a problem with Fedora 9 (64bit) or is it some configuration thing I've missed?

Comment: Since Fedora 9 is no longer supported, I'd strongly suggest that you update regardless. See http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Releases

Comment: I know I _should_, but i want to know if I _need_ to in order to get all my RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just re-download a kernel and re-compile it, including 64GB RAM support. Your kernel is just not supporting more than 4 GIGs right now.

Comment: Is there something special I need to do in order to include 64GB RAM support, or is that just dependent on the kernel that I download?  Should I get the latest kernel (2.6.32.7), the kernel that I am running (2.6.27.25), or the latest sub version of the kernel that I'm running (2.6.27.45)? I don't want to break my existing install.

Comment: All kernels have the option available. It's a matter of selecting it. Sadly, I have never compiled my own kernel in Fedora and do not know what specific steps you need to take in order to not break any automation - but on that level, Google can help!

If you're lucky, you may already have the source for the kernel available - for me, with Gentoo, they are under /usr/src but I am not sure where they are for Fedora. You may be able to get them from yum.
If you compile a kernel that doesn't work -- just boot from the old kernel!

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot and give you a check if all goes well.

Comment: I couldn't find the option for 64GB support in gconfig with the 2.6.27 linux kernel.  I'm going to try again tonight, though I couldn't really find any good sources of information about that particular config flag.

Comment: Here, take a look at this article. I hope it helps: http://www.linux.com/archive/feed/119287


At the worst, you may need to patch the kernel (easier than it sounds) or download a pre-patched / custom kernel (safer than it sounds).

Answer (score 0):

You can also install a 32 bit Linux, and install the bigmem kernel.
Then supports 64 GB ram on a 32 bit system (if CPU >= Pentium 4)